# Using a Visual Studio extension in 2 workspaces

Tags: visual-studio-extensions

I am using a Visual studio extension in two Workspaces but the configuration needs to be different for each (it points to a specific network location which is not the same for both workspaces).

Is there a way to either have 2 versions of the extension or 2 configurations?  The extension is called Openhab and by default it is enable globally.

Answer (score 0):

If this two workspaces are on two different devices/machines, by changing/unchecking the `Synchronize settings across devices` in Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts, the settings for VS can be different.

If the configuration is not related to VS, but is related to the project/solution, is it contained in one certain file in your project/solution? If yes, you may need to change the specific file to change it.

If this two workspaces are on the same machine and the settings are based on Visual Studio, then VS will remember the settings. Perhaps you can consider exporting and importing settings? (Tools > Import and Export Settings…)

Besides, it is not possible to have 2 different versions of the same extension in one VS.